# Rails 5.2.3 - Show tree of Categories ordered by the total of their associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently using the [Ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to render 500+ categories and sub-categories (they can go up to 3 levels deep).

Now, what I'm trying to do is:

1. Show only those categories/sub-categories with associated
   transactions.
2. Order those categories by:

   - The sum of the `:amount` of those associated transactions.
   - And also order them by hierarchy.
3. Print the total next to each category name.

Here's an example of what I'm hoping to achieve:

```
Travel = $1500
Travel > Air = $1000
Travel > Ground = $250
Business = $500
Business > Services = $250
Business > Services > Marketing = $75
# etc...
```

This is what my models look like:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transactions
  has_ancestry
end

class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :category
end
```

So far I was able to *ALMOST* get there by doing:

```
# app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
def index
  # Get all of the root categories
  @primary_categories = Category.where(ancestry: nil)
end

# app/views/categories/index.html.erb
<% @primary_categories.each do |primary_category| %>
  <% primary_category_total = Transaction.where(account_id: current_user, category_id: primary_category.subtree).sum(:amount) %>

  <% if primary_category_total != 0.0 %> 
    <%= link_to primary_category.name, category_path(primary_category) %>
    <%= number_to_currency primary_category_total %>

    <% if primary_category.has_children? && primary_category_total != 0.0 %> 
      <% primary_category.children.each do |secondary_category| %>
        <% secondary_category_total = Transaction.where(account_id: current_user, category_id: primary_category.subtree).sum(:amount) %>

        <% if secondary_category_total != 0.0 %> 
          <%= link_to secondary_category.name, category_path(secondary_category) %>
          <%= number_to_currency secondary_category_total %>

          <% if secondary_category.has_children? && secondary_category_total != 0.0 %>
            <% secondary_category.children.each do |tertiary_category| %>
            <% tertiary_category_total = Transaction.where(account_id: current_user, category_id: primary_category.subtree).sum(:amount) %>

            <% if tertiary_category_total != 0.0 %> 
              <%= link_to tertiary_category.name, category_path(tertiary_category) %>
              <%= number_to_currency tertiary_category.transactions.sum(:amount) %>
# etc...
```

But this generates an insane amount of queries which it's painfully slow, not to mention that I now have a bunch of complex code on my view. And of course, they are not sorted by total.

How else should I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial an error (based on Jacob's [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58090117/2492092)) I came up with a solution that performs significantly better, removed complexity from the controller and views and does everything on my requirements list from my first post.

I still think there is room for optimization and clean up but here it goes:

**app/models/transaction.rb**

```
  scope :by_user_category, ->(user, category) do 
    where(account: user.accounts, category: category.subtree)
  end
```

**app/models/category.rb**

```
  def balance(user)
    Transaction.by_user_category(user, self).sum(:amount)
  end

  def self.spending_by(user)
    categories_with_spending = []

    categories_depth_0 = Category.where(ancestry: nil) # Get the root categories
    categories_depth_0.each do |cat_depth_0|
      category_depth_0_balance = cat_depth_0.balance(user)

      if category_depth_0_balance < 0  # "Root category exists and has a balance"
        categories_depth_1_with_spending = []
        categories_depth_1 = Category.find_by_id(cat_depth_0).children # Get the sub-categories

        if !categories_depth_1.empty? # "Sub-category exists"
          categories_depth_1.each do |cat_depth_1|
            category_depth_1_balance = cat_depth_1.balance(user)

            if category_depth_1_balance < 0 # "Sub-category exists and has a balance"
              categories_depth_2_with_spending = []
              categories_depth_2 = Category.find_by_id(cat_depth_1).children

              if !categories_depth_2.empty? # Sub-category has child
                categories_depth_2.each do |cat_depth_2|
                  category_depth_2_balance = cat_depth_2.balance(user)

                  if category_depth_2_balance < 0  # Sub-category child has a balance
                    categories_depth_2_with_spending << {
                      category: cat_depth_2,
                      balance: category_depth_2_balance
                    }
                  end
                end
              end

              if categories_depth_2_with_spending != nil
                # Passing child sub-categories to parent sub-categories
                categories_depth_1_with_spending << {
                  category: cat_depth_1,
                  balance: category_depth_1_balance,
                  sub_categories: categories_depth_2_with_spending.sort_by { |c| c[:balance] }
                }
              end
            end
          end

          if categories_depth_1_with_spending != nil
            # Passing sub-categories to root category
            categories_with_spending << {
              category: cat_depth_0,
              balance: category_depth_0_balance,
              sub_categories: categories_depth_1_with_spending.sort_by { |c| c[:balance] }
            }
          end
        else
          # "Root exists but has no sub-categories"
          categories_with_spending << {
            category: cat_depth_0,
            balance: category_depth_0_balance
          }
        end
      end
    end

    return categories_with_spending.sort_by { |c| c[:balance] }
  end
```

**app/controllers/categories_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @categories = Category.spending_by(current_user)
  end
```

**app/views/categories/index.html.erb**

```
  <% @categories.each do |cat_depth_0| %>
    <section class="app-card app-amount-summary app-categories__card">
      <%= render 'category_depth_0', category: cat_depth_0 %>

      <% if cat_depth_0[:sub_categories] %>
        <ul class="app-category-list">
          <% cat_depth_0[:sub_categories].each do |cat_depth_1| %>
            <%= render 'category_depth_1', category: cat_depth_1 %>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
    </section>
  <% end %>
```

**app/views/categories/_category_depth_0.html.erb**

```
<header class="app-card-header">
  <h3 class="app-card-header__h3">
    <%= link_to category[:category].name, category_path(category[:category].id) %>
  </h3>
  <p class="app-card-header__balance"><%= number_to_currency category[:balance] %></p>
</header>
```

`_category_depth_1.html.erb` works exactly like `_category_depth_0.html.erb` but with a different structure so I skipped it on this example.

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat emptor:**

Everything below should be considered pseudo-code. I didn't test any of this, I'm not trying to make it copy & paste ready. It's just a starting point to help you *start* a refactor.

### In your Model

You want to get stuff like `Transaction.where(account_id: current_user, category_id: primary_category.subtree).sum(:amount)` out of your views.

You could create a method and / or scope to return the transaction total. For example:

```rb
# app/models/transaction.rb
scope :by_user_category, ->(user, category) do 
  where(account: user, category: category.subtree)
end

# app/models/category.rb
def user_transaction_amount(user)
  Transaction.by_user_category(user, self).sum(:amount)
end
```

### In your Controller

You should [Eager load](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) the children. You know you're going to need them, so do it all at once. (*with-in reason, see below*)

You mention 500+ categories, is this paginated? If so, do so in [batches](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches).

### In your View

Notice that repeating code? Try using a [partial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) to DRY that up. For example:

```
# app/views/categories/_category.html.erb
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <% category_total = category.user_transaction_amount(current_user) %>
  <% return if category_total == 0.0 %>
  <%= link_to category.name, category_path(category) %>
  <%= number_to_currency category_total %>
  <% if category.has_children? && category_total != 0.0 %> 
      <% category.children.each do |secondary_category| %>
        <%= render category, category: secondary_category %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>


# app/views/categories/index.html.erb
<% @primary_categories.each do |primary_category| %>
  <% render 'categories', category: primary_category %>
<% end %>
```

This could still use some improvement. View templates should be mostly html statements and this is 100% ruby. You could probably move this all into a helper, or even [render](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) directly from a controller action.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I'm going to give your approach a try.

To clarify, while I have 500+ categories I only expect to render maybe 30 after I run through all of the transaction totals so I don't have any pagination (for now).